# How would I do this AJAX in Node?

Tags: node.js

I can write this Instagram API call using jQuery, but I'm not sure how to get Node and/or socket to do the same.  Any help?

```
function getData(url){
  $.ajax({
    url: url,
    dataType :"jsonp",
    success: function(data){
      console.log('success');
      console.log(data);
    }
  });
}

var tag = "myTag";
var accessToken = "myAccessToken"
var url = 'https://api.instagram.com/v1/tags/' +  tag + '/media/recent?access_token=' + accessToken + '&callback=callBackFunction';
getData(url);
```

Answer (score 5):

Another way to do this would be to use [request](https://github.com/mikeal/request) module

```
var request = require('request');

request('your url',function(error,response,body){

 //body will contain the response from the api endpoint.

});
```

Comment: Brilliant. This was eluding me.

Answer (score 2):

This should work as you would like it to (adding some extra `STATUS`, `HEADERS` and `BODY` markers) :

```js
var http = require('http');

var myhost = "https://api.instagram.com/";
var tag = "myTag";
var accessToken = "myAccessToken"
var myurl = tag + '/media/recent?access_token=' + accessToken + '&callback=callBackFunction';

var options = {
  hostname: myhost,
  port: 80,
  path: myurl,
  method: 'GET'
};

var req = http.request(options, function(res) {
  console.log('STATUS: ' + res.statusCode);
  console.log('HEADERS: ' + JSON.stringify(res.headers));
  res.setEncoding('utf8');
  res.on('data', function (chunk) {
    console.log('BODY: ' + chunk);
  });
});
```